# Combine awaitables like Promise.all

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, future, python-asyncio

In asynchronous JavaScript, it is easy to run tasks in parallel and wait for all of them to complete using `Promise.all`:

```
async function bar(i) {
  console.log('started', i);
  await delay(1000);
  console.log('finished', i);
}

async function foo() {
    await Promise.all([bar(1), bar(2)]);
}

// This works too:
async function my_all(promises) {
    for (let p of promises) await p;
}

async function foo() {
    await my_all([bar(1), bar(2), bar(3)]);
}
```

I tried to rewrite the latter in python:

```
import asyncio

async def bar(i):
  print('started', i)
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  print('finished', i)

async def aio_all(seq):
  for f in seq:
    await f

async def main():
  await aio_all([bar(i) for i in range(10)])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

But it executes my tasks sequentially.

What is the simplest way to await multiple awaitables?
Why doesn't my approach work?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The equivalent would be using [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather):

```
import asyncio

async def bar(i):
  print('started', i)
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  print('finished', i)

async def main():
  await asyncio.gather(*[bar(i) for i in range(10)])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

> Why doesn't my approach work?

Because when you `await` each item in `seq`, you block that coroutine. So in essence, you have synchronous code masquerading as async. If you really *wanted* to, you could implement your own version of `asyncio.gather` using `loop.create_task` or `asyncio.ensure_future`.

**EDIT**

The original answer used the lower-level [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait).

Comment: please mention asyncio.gather too

Comment: Is the main difference between `wait` and `gather` that `wait` allows a `timeout` argument?

Comment: asyncio.wait is the more low level way of waiting. Also in 3.8 passing coroutines to wait directly is deprecated. Please rewrite your answer or update with a snippet using asyncio.gather as it's closer to Promise.all.

Comment: What's the difference if the function returns a value?

Comment: Very good. I got `Task got bad yield: <coroutine object ...>` because I was using `gather(f(x) for x in xs)` instead of `gather(*[f(x) for x in xs])`

Answer (score 23):

I  noticed that [asyncio.gather()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently) may be a better way to await other than asyncio.wait() if we want ordered results.

As the docs indicates, the order of result values from asyncio.gather() method corresponds to the order of awaitables in aws. However, the order of result values from asyncio.wait() won't do the same thing.You can test it.

Answer (score 16):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather

`asyncio.gather()` will return the list of output from each async function calls.

```
import asyncio

async def bar(i):
    print('started', i)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('finished', i)
    return i

async def main():
    values = await asyncio.gather(*[bar(i) for i in range(10)])
    print(values)

asyncio.run(main())
```

This method, gather, takes arbitrary number of args for the concurrent jobs instead of a list, so we unpack.

It's very common to need this intermediate value, `values` in my eg, instead of designing your function/method to have side effects.

Answer (score 4):

As of [Python 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently):

A more modern way to create and run tasks concurrently and wait for their completion is [asyncio.TaskGroup](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.TaskGroup).

... although, I couldn't find any reason why TaskGroup should be preferred over gather

Comment: Can you please put an example without the `with` keyword

Answer (score 3):

To make this work the only change needed is to use [asyncio.as_completed()](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) to create an iterator of coroutines (awaitables) you can use for the `for`-loop:

```
async def asyncio_all(aws):
    for future in asyncio.as_completed(aws)
        await future
```

When applied to your code:

```
import asyncio

async def bar(i):
  print('started', i)
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  print('finished', i)

async def aio_all(seq):
  for f in asyncio.as_completed(seq):
    await f

async def main():
  await aio_all([bar(i) for i in range(10)])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

```
started 1
started 0
started 2
started 6
started 8
started 7
started 5
started 9
started 4
started 3
finished 1
finished 0
finished 2
finished 6
finished 8
finished 7
finished 5
finished 9
finished 4
finished 3
```

This comes closest to JavaScript `Promise.all`. However, using `asyncio.gather` or `asyncio.TaskGroup` (from v3.11) seems to be the more Pythonic way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer mentioned the more recent `TaskGroup` that behaves very similarly to `gather`.

The main difference, as explained [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently), is that `TaskGroup` will cancel the remaining coroutines in case an exception is thrown in one of the tasks.