# Getting asyncio to run a function in order (Python 3)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

Here is a simple example of using `asyncio` to print out numbers from 0 to 9.

**Problem:** Sometimes the code prints out the numbers from 0 to 7, then prints 9, then 8. Especially when you set `ThreadPoolExecutor` to a smaller number like 4 or 5.

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
9
8
```

How do you get it to **always** print in sequence from 0 to 9? Why did it not print in sequence?

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

**Code**

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


async def printThreaded(THREAD_POOL, length):   
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = []
    for i in range(length):
        futures.append(loop.run_in_executor(THREAD_POOL, echo, i))
    await asyncio.wait(futures)


def echo(i):
    print(i)


THREAD_POOL = ThreadPoolExecutor(16)
with THREAD_POOL:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    length = 10
    loop.run_until_complete(printThreaded(THREAD_POOL, length))
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377319/combine-awaitables-like-promise-all)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What happens in your code now?

You create list of coroutines (`futures`) that will each run `echo` in thread pool, than you start them all at once (`await asyncio.wait(futures)`). Since multiple `echo` running in same time and each prints on being run, all this prints can happen any time.

### What do you want to do?

You probably don't really want to run coroutines in order (otherwise you can just call it in loop without `asyncio`), you want to **run them in thread pool concurrently, but print their results in order coroutines were created**

In this case you should:

1. split actual work that will happen in thread from
   printing it
2. probably prefer to use [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) to get computed results in order
3. finally print ordered results you got in main thread

### Summary

Here's modified version of your code that does explained above:

```
import time
from random import randint

import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


async def printThreaded(THREAD_POOL, length):   
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    # compute concurrently:
    coroutines = []
    for i in range(length):
        coroutine = loop.run_in_executor(THREAD_POOL, get_result, i)
        coroutines.append(coroutine)
    results = await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)

    # print ordered results:
    for res in results:
        print(res)



def get_result(i):

    time.sleep(randint(0, 2))  # actual work, reason you delegate 'get_result' function to threaed

    return i  # compute and return, but not print yet


THREAD_POOL = ThreadPoolExecutor(4)
with THREAD_POOL:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    length = 10
    loop.run_until_complete(printThreaded(THREAD_POOL, length))
```