# Python How to send multiple files

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How to make bot upload multiple image with content description. i can add multiple lines it works, but bot slows posting when it has more than 5 `await bot.send` line. i need to add few images so how to do it if possible in same line.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await bot.send_file(ctx.message.channel, "Image1.png", content="Image1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to run multiple asynchronous tasks in one await.

You should use `asyncio.wait`:

```
import asyncio

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
  files = ...  # Set the 5 files (or more ?) you want to upload here
  await asyncio.wait([bot.send_file(ctx.message.channel, f['filename'], content=f['content'] for f in files)])
```

(See [Combine awaitables like Promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377319/combine-awaitables-like-promise-all))

Comment: You're missing a `)` in your comprehension: `[bot.send_file(ctx.message.channel, f['filename'], content=f['content']) for f in files]`

Comment: `files` is the list of files you want to upload. According to you question, you want to upload multiple files. You shoul replace `...` with the files you want to upload.

Comment: More like `files = [{"filename": "image1.png", "content": "image1"}, {"filename": "image2.png", "content": "image2"}, {"filename": "image3.png", "content": "image3"}]` according to my snippet, but you can edit things according to what you want/need.

Comment: @Blusky yes its working now. except 1 problem it won't send by one by one in order. everytime when command used it sends randomly up and down order. example  image3, image5, image1, image 2 like this.

Comment: It's normal, it's uploaded simultaneously (so it's faster). But you can't know for sure which one will be the first.