# how to prevent blocking in python asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Assume the following code:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def say_after():
    for i in range(10):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("first function")
async def say_after2():
    for i in range(10):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("second function")

async def main():
    await say_after()
    await say_after2()
asyncio.run(main())
```

It would first print `"first function"` 10 times and after function `say_after` is finished then it would print `"second function"` 10 times. now i want to run both functions at the same time like 2 threads (like parallel) with `asycio` not sequential executing. how do i do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine awaitables like Promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377319/combine-awaitables-like-promise-all)

Comment: What Python version is this code running on? In Python 3.6 `asyncio` has no `run` attribute.

Comment: it's 3.7. `.run` is new. no matter if you have any idea in 3.6 would be good as well

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task