# Python multiprocessing - How to modify an object?

Tags: python, class, object, methods, multiprocessing

My class embeds a method to process the object. But when I use multiprocessing, the original object is not modified. More generally, how to achieve multiprocessing of objects using their methods ? (I use python 3.8)

Here is my code :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.level=1
    
    def process(self):
        self.level=2
        # and other many things that modify the object...
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    objects = [MyObject() for i in range(10)]
    pool = Pool(3)
    async_results = []
    for o in objects:
        async_results.append(pool.apply_async(o.process, [], {}))
    pool.close()
    for r in async_results:
        r.get()
    for o in objects:
        print(o.level)      # unfortunately, 1, not 2
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978372/python-process-dictionary-using-multiprocessingpython-3-7/66978521#66978521) might be relevant

Answer (score 1):

Multipriocessing serializes your objects and sends them to other processes. It then gets back serialized objects as a return value. So, there is no way for those remote processes to modify the object, in this original memory space, that you sent to them.

Instead, take the returned objects `async_results` and use those, or alternately,  modify `objects` here using data from these results.

Comment: No way to modify the object? I don't think so. What if what you are passing is a proxy to the object? How do you think managed `dict` instances such as are returned by `multiprocessing.Manager().dict()` work?

Comment: @Booboo That is a great idea. Strictly speaking, it is still true that the  parameter object is not changes, but yes, it does achieve what hew wants.

Comment: The parameter object is an object (class MyObjectProxy) that ultimately delegates to an instance of `MyObject` (well, actually `__main__.MyObject`), which is most definitely changed. And this delegated to object (the "delegatee") can be obtained; you just need a method in `MyObject` that returns `self`. I've updated my answer with a demo.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create "proxyable", managed objects just like the ones returned by the `SyncManager` instance that is created when you call `multiprocessing.Manager()`, for example managed `dict` instances:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, NamespaceProxy
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.level=1

    def process(self):
        self.level=2
        # and other many things that modify the object...

    def delegatee(self):
        return self

# Must explicitly create a customized proxy if attributes in addition to methods will be accessed
# And that forces us to name each method, e.g. process:
class MyObjectProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('__getattribute__', '__getattr__', '__setattr__', 'process', 'delegatee')

    def process(self):
        callmethod = NamespaceProxy.__getattribute__(self, '_callmethod')
        return callmethod('process')

    def delegatee(self):
        callmethod = NamespaceProxy.__getattribute__(self, '_callmethod')
        return callmethod('delegatee')


    """
    or you can just use the following generic signature for each of your methods:

    def process(self, *args, **kwds):
        callmethod = NamespaceProxy.__getattribute__(self, '_callmethod')
        return callmethod('process', args, kwds)
    """


class MyObjectManager(BaseManager):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyObjectManager.register('MyObject', MyObject, MyObjectProxy)
    with MyObjectManager() as manager:
        objects = [manager.MyObject() for i in range(10)]
        pool = Pool(3)
        async_results = []
        for o in objects:
            async_results.append(pool.apply_async(o.process, [], {}))
            # or just:
            #async_results.append(pool.apply_async(o.process))
        pool.close()
        for r in async_results:
            r.get()
        for o in objects:
            print(o.level)
        obj0 = objects[0]
        print(type(obj0))
        delegatee = obj0.delegatee()
        print(type(delegatee))
        print('delegatee level =', delegatee.level)
```

Prints:

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
<class '__main__.MyObjectProxy'>
<class '__main__.MyObject'>
delegatee level = 2
```

But note that each method invocation or attribute access is via a proxy and is more or less equivalent to a remote procedure call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, maybe more simple, in case if only the attributes are concerned :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.level = 1
    
    def process(self):
        self.level = 2      # modified attribute
        self.name = "xxx"   # new attribute
        return self.__dict__
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    objects = [MyObject(i) for i in range(10)]
    pool = Pool(3)
    async_results = []
    for o in objects:
        async_results.append(pool.apply_async(o.process, [], {}))
    pool.close()
    results=[]
    for r in async_results:
        results.append(r.get())
    for r in results:
        for o in objects:
            if o.id == r["id"]:
                o.__dict__.update(r)
                break
    for o in objects:
        print(o.__dict__)
```